# Working with Watson Assistant / Watson Conversation from Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

I'm doing a simple chatbot with watson. I have a python script. Assume script is this for simplicity:

```
x=5
x
```

And in watson i want to return :

```
result is 5
```

However, I'm not sure, how to interact with python. My research showed that it is something related to NodeJS and JSON, but I couldn't find any example or tutorial that suites my requirements.

Could someone route me what course of actions should i take or any documentation?

Comment: If you want to interact with Watson Conversation / Watson Assistant from Python, check out this tool. You can use it for a dialog and for retrieving / uploading workspaces: https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/

Answer (score 2):

The data between Watson Assistant and a client, an application, is exchanged as JSON-formatted data. The service itself has a REST API and you can use it from any programming language or with command-line tools. [For Python, there is even a SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/).

There are some samples written in Python. I recommend my own code :). There is [a tool I wrote to interact with Watson Assistant / Watson Conversation](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) ([blog entry is here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/04/watson-conversation-manage-workspaces/)). Another [Python sample is what I called EgoBot](https://github.com/data-henrik/bluemix-egobot/) ([blog is here](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/06/egobot-fun-with-slightly-mutating.html)). It shows how you can even change the dialog itself from within the chatbot. Basically, you can tell the bot to learn stuff. The examples should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, @data_henrik . I tried first tutorial, that didn't work . Than I tried efobot tutorial. I set up all service credentials. That returning errors due to no parathesis in script, i fixed that. And then when I run python egobot.py -setup -name egoEnglish -lang en I receive error no module named 'watson-developer-cloud' What that may mean?

Comment: Did you install the SDK that I linked? `pip install watson-developer-cloud`.

Comment: Double check the version of Python being used, as well as any other packages (like json, pandas, etc.) that might need to get installed into your environment.